# Input elements does not align properly after jQuery show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got multiple input items aligned horizontally as a list. I set their display equal to none, and later, upon clicking a different element, they all show up, but not as an ordered horizontally list but as one long row from upside down.

How can I remedy this, so upon show() the items will show up normally, like this:

```
*********
   ***
```

And not as a long list upside down:

```
*
*
*
*
```

etc...

I tried to use `$("input").attr("display", "flex")`, which didn't work.
The relevant code:

```
input {
    display: none;
}


<input type="image" src="1\boy.png" id="kid" alt="שי גבע" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy1.png" id="kid"  alt="רונן חתואל"/>
<input type="image" src="1\girl.png" id="kid"  alt="חן דואק" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy3.png" id="kid"  alt="שימי לוי" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy2.png" id="kid"  alt="גיא מרוז" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy4.png" id="kid"  alt="אבי רון" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl8.png" id="kid"  alt="שמחה ריף" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl13.png" id="kid" alt="ברכה קצר" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl10.png" id="kid" alt="מורל מויאל" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy5.png" id="kid" alt="שמשון גיבור" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy6.png" id="kid" alt="איתי חיימוב" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy7.png" id="kid" alt="גרגורי קייקוב" />

$("#start").click(function() {
    $('input').show('slow');
    $("#start").hide();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: share your html+javascript code+CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the jQuery method **[`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)** instead when you want to set up the CSS rules from the JS code :

```
$("input").css("display","inline");
```

If you want to show just the clicked input you have to use the current object `$(this)` like :

```
$(this).css("display","inline");
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("#start").click(function() {
  $('input').css("display","inline");
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="image" src="1\boy.png" id="kid" alt="שי גבע" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy1.png" id="kid"  alt="רונן חתואל"/>
<input type="image" src="1\girl.png" id="kid"  alt="חן דואק" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy3.png" id="kid"  alt="שימי לוי" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy2.png" id="kid"  alt="גיא מרוז" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy4.png" id="kid"  alt="אבי רון" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl8.png" id="kid"  alt="שמחה ריף" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl13.png" id="kid" alt="ברכה קצר" />
<input type="image" src="1\girl10.png" id="kid" alt="מורל מויאל" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy5.png" id="kid" alt="שמשון גיבור" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy6.png" id="kid" alt="איתי חיימוב" />
<input type="image" src="1\boy7.png" id="kid" alt="גרגורי קייקוב" />

<button id="start">start</button>
```